# how to set order by (specific order) in Underscore js - Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array , i need final output based on the custom sort order CategoryId:(5,9,14,1,9,3) based on the TypeID

```
        console.log(_.sortBy(arr, 'CategoryID'));
```

I can able to sort CategoryId,  But i want sort by CategoryID with that specific order .

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src= 
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore.js"> 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var arr = [ 
            {name: 'kim', salary: 4000,CategoryId:3, TypeId:1}, 
            {name: 'shelly', salary: 5000,CategoryId:14, TypeId:1}, 
            {name: 'don', salary: 100,CategoryId:9, TypeId:1}, 
            {name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5, TypeId:2}, 
            {name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5, TypeId:1}, 
          {name: 'joh', salary: 3450,CategoryId:9, TypeId:1}, 
          {name: 'joe', salary: 5100,CategoryId:1, TypeId:1}, 
          {name: 'moore', salary: 5100,CategoryId:14, TypeId:2}, 
          {name: 'wane', salary: 1500,CategoryId:14, TypeId:2}, 
          {name: 'dick', salary: 400,CategoryId:3, TypeId:1}                
        ]; 
        console.log(_.sortBy(arr, 'CategoryId')); 
    </script> 
</body>
```

I expect the result set specific order for the
CategoryId:(5,9,14,1,3)

Final Output :

```
const output = [{
  name: 'mark',
  salary: 4500,
  CategoryId: 5,
  TypeId: 1,
}, {
  name: 'joh',
  salary: 3450,
  CategoryId: 9,
  TypeId: 1,
}, {
  name: 'don',
  salary: 100,
  CategoryId: 9,
  TypeId: 1,
}, {
  name: 'joh',
  salary: 3450,
  CategoryId: 9,
  TypeId: 1,
}, {
  name: 'shelly',
  salary: 5000,
  CategoryId: 14,
  TypeId: 1,
}, {
  name: 'joe',
  salary: 5100,
  CategoryId: 1,
  TypeId: 1,
}, {
  name: 'kim',
  salary: 4000,
  CategoryId: 3,
  TypeId: 1,
}, {
  name: 'mark',
  salary: 4500,
  CategoryId: 5,
  TypeId: 2,
}, {
  name: 'moore',
  salary: 5100,
  CategoryId: 14,
  TypeId: 2,
}, {
  name: 'wane',
  salary: 1500,
  CategoryId: 14,
  TypeId: 2,
}];
```

Comment: according to which rule is this sorted: (5,9,14,1,9,3) ?

Comment: I need output the format

Comment: What's the logic that leads to 5, 9, 14, 1, 9, 3? Just a hardcoded goal? And what criterion decides which 9 should be put in which of the two 9 locations?

Comment: I have updated the code.  I need to group by based on TypeID, I need order by specfic categoryId (5,9,14,1,9,3)

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like? What should the grouping look like?

Comment: I am sorry, i have updated the code.

Comment: I don't see any output. It just says `Final Output : `.

Comment: {name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5, TypeId:1}, 
{name: 'joh', salary: 3450,CategoryId:9, TypeId:1}, 
{name: 'don', salary: 100,CategoryId:9, TypeId:1}, 
{name: 'joh', salary: 3450,CategoryId:9, TypeId:1}, 
{name: 'shelly', salary: 5000,CategoryId:14, TypeId:1}, 
{name: 'joe', salary: 5100,CategoryId:1, TypeId:1}, 
{name: 'kim', salary: 4000,CategoryId:3, TypeId:1}, 
{name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5, TypeId:2}, 
{name: 'moore', salary: 5100,CategoryId:14, TypeId:2}, 
 {name: 'wane', salary: 1500,CategoryId:14, TypeId:2},

Comment: I need the final output the above, I need to group by TypeID and specific CategoryID order

Comment: Please post that in the question itself as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specified your desired order as an array, you could sort based on the index of each category *within* that array.

```js
var arr = [ {name: 'kim', salary: 4000,CategoryId:3, TypeId:1}, {name: 'shelly', salary: 5000,CategoryId:14, TypeId:1}, {name: 'don', salary: 100,CategoryId:9, TypeId:1}, {name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5, TypeId:2}, {name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5, TypeId:1}, {name: 'joh', salary: 3450,CategoryId:9, TypeId:1}, {name: 'joe', salary: 5100,CategoryId:1, TypeId:1}, {name: 'moore', salary: 5100,CategoryId:14, TypeId:2}, {name: 'wane', salary: 1500,CategoryId:14, TypeId:2}, {name: 'dick', salary: 400,CategoryId:3, TypeId:1} ];

const categoryOrder = [5,9,14,1,9,3];

const result = [...arr].sort((a,b) => {
  return a.TypeId === b.TypeId
    ? categoryOrder.indexOf(a.CategoryId) - categoryOrder.indexOf(b.CategoryId)
    : a.TypeId - b.TypeId;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to make your own custom sort function as this could not be achieved using underscore.js

```
var tempArray = [
    {name: 'kim', salary: 4000, CategoryId: 3, TypeId: 1},
    {name: 'shelly', salary: 5000, CategoryId: 4, TypeId: 1},
    {name: 'don', salary: 100, CategoryId: 9, TypeId: 1},
    {name: 'mark', salary: 4500, CategoryId: 5, TypeId: 2},
    {name: 'mark', salary: 4500, CategoryId: 5, TypeId: 1},
    {name: 'joh', salary: 3450, CategoryId: 9, TypeId: 1},
    {name: 'joe', salary: 5100, CategoryId: 1, TypeId: 1},
    {name: 'moore', salary: 5100, CategoryId: 14, TypeId: 2},
    {name: 'wane', salary: 1500, CategoryId: 14, TypeId: 2},
    {name: 'dick', salary: 400, CategoryId: 3, TypeId: 1}
]

function sort(order, array) {
    result = []
    order.forEach(o => {
        let output = array.filter(element => element.CategoryId === o)
        // To further sort it by type id we can now use sort
        output = _.sortBy(output, 'TypeId')
        result = result.concat(output)
    })
    // For output to be this way 
    // TypeID: (1) - order by : 5,9,14,1,9,3, TypeID: 2 
    // Order by : 5,9,14,11,9,3.
    // we can use groupBy
    return _.groupBy(result, 'TypeId')
}

sort([5, 9, 14, 1, 9, 3], tempArray)
```

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Yes. Almost correct, I need output like TypeID: (1) - order by : 5,9,14,1,9,3, TypeID: 2 Order by : 5,9,14,11,9,3.   In future, if the data has TypeID: 3, it will go like this.

Comment: can I pass typeId to sort function like `sort(typeId, order, array)`?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://underscorejs.org/#objects

sortBy_.sortBy(list, iteratee, [context]) 
Returns a (stably) sorted copy of list, ranked in ascending order by the results of running each value through iteratee. iteratee may also be the string name of the property to sort by (eg. length).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var arr = [
         {name: 'kim', salary: 4000,CategoryId:3},
         {name: 'shelly', salary: 5000,CategoryId:4},
         {name: 'don', salary: 100,CategoryId:9},
         {name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5},
         {name: 'mark', salary: 4500,CategoryId:5},
         {name: 'joh', salary: 3450,CategoryId:9},
         {name: 'joe', salary: 5100,CategoryId:1},
         {name: 'moore', salary: 5100,CategoryId:14},
         {name: 'wane', salary: 1500,CategoryId:14},
         {name: 'dick', salary: 400,CategoryId:3}
     ];
     console.log(_.sortBy(arr, 'CategoryId'));
 </script>
```

Comment: Based on PO requirements ordering should be implemented with specific manner that are defined in dedicated array.